# "Next" key doesn't work

Tags: button, ios6, sdk, keyboard, uitextfield

I have two TextFiels. On first I set "Next" button on keybord, but the button "Done" are working on the second field. I wrote this code.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
if (theTextField == self.loginField) {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
} else if (theTextField == self.passField) {
    [self.passField becomeFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
}
```

Maybe I was wrong in something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        if(textField == self.loginField)
        {
            [self.passField becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if(textField == self.passField)
        {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        }
        return YES;
    }

In xib, select LoginField - Return key set as "Next", Select PassField - Return key as "Done"/"Next".
```

Comment: Are you connect text filed delegate in xib?

Comment: Import UITextFieldDelegate.